# change position of tooltip when resizing window

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm using angular to build a portfolio and wanted to use the [material tooltips](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview). When the site is viewed in the browser (wide screen), I want the position to be right. If the site is viewed on a mobile device, I want it to be displayed below the element.
Currently, when I refresh the page, the tooltip displays at the correct position. However, I have a problem changing the position when resizing the browser. The position does not seem to change.

here is the code I have at the moment.

HTML:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faAddressCard" class="has-tooltip" #tooltip="matTooltip" matTooltip="About me" [matTooltipPosition]="tooltipPosition" matTooltipClass="tooltip"></fa-icon>
```

TS:

```
tooltipPosition = window.innerWidth < 600 ? 'below' : 'right';

ngOnInit(): void {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateTooltipPosition);
    this.updateTooltipPosition()
}

updateTooltipPosition() {
    let position = window.innerWidth < 600 ? 'below' : 'right';
    let tooltips = document.getElementsByClassName('has-tooltip')
    for (let i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
      tooltips[i].setAttribute('ng-reflect-position', position)
    }
}
```

Any tips to solve this problem are welcome! I'm a starting developer so any other remarks towards my code are appreciated too!

Comment: Media query?...

Comment: This seems to have very little to do with typescript.

Comment: @CharlesBamford, I removed the typescript tag, thanks.

Comment: @GetSet, the problem is not the listening to the resize event. I can console log the size and see that the event is called. My question is how do I set the position of the tooltip